# Why is this support interval not (-1, 1) of 1-x^2 for x < 1?

Tags: real-analysis

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)

From the closed support section, we see that between at -1 or 1 $1-x^2$ is 0, yet we say the support is [-1, 1] and not (-1, 1)? I thought a support was the set of the domain which does not map to 0?

Further it talks to the closure of the set ... why is the set closure not also (-1, 1)?

Comment: This question is ff topic for this site.

Answer (score 2):

> If the domain of f is a topological space, the support of f is instead
>   defined as the smallest **closed set** containing all points not mapped to
>   zero.

Euclidean space is a topological space. The closure of a set is the union of an open set and the set of all its limit points, that is all points that are arbitrarily close to a point within the open set. (-1,1) is open, while [-1,1] is closed because it includes the two limit points -1 and 1.